# parsing String to Ints

Tags: java, object

We have an assignment/project where we create a parking lot with several different objects then typically each week we add/improve on it.  This week we were given a .txt file with lines that look like this `"Bicycle%4%2%ABC40%false"` or `"Auto%22%7%ABC21%false"`.  Each `%` is used as a delimiter denoting a separate attribute (speed, passenger capacity, serial number, and boolean lock status for bikes) for the respective object (car or bicycle).

We need to read through the file and create a new object in an array with that line using split.  What I'm having trouble with is taking the number which is currently a string, parsing it as an int or boolean, then adding that to the new Bicycle (or Auto). Just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Also wondering if my "if" logic is right for if it says Bicycle to start creating a bicycle?

**Update:**

I think I have the parsing issue figured out, but now it's saying that it can't find my attributes for bicycle... saying "Cannot find symbol"  So close!

Here's my code:

```
public class Driver
{
    private static Object myBicycle;
    private static Object myAuto;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Vehicles.txt"));
        ArrayList<Object> myVehicles = new ArrayList<Object>();

        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String [] data = line.split("%");

            if (data[0].equals("Bicycle"))
            {
                speed = (Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                PassCap = (Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
                serialNumber = (Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
                locked = (Boolean.parseBoolean(data[4]));
                brand = Brand.randomBrand();
                Bicycle myBicycle = new Bicycle(speed, PassCap, serialNumber, locked, brand);
                myVehicles.add(myBicycle);
            }
```

Comment: Whats up there for parsing by the way is just me guessing on what to do

Comment: I think you need to call setters like this: `myBicycle.setSpeed(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));` Also, you need to initialize `myBicycle`. Do you have classed defined for bicycle or Auto? Your list should not be String from what it seems like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your implementation is, but you could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/home/buddha/MYDRIVE/exploring/java/src/Vehicles.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> myVehicles = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] data = line.split("%");
        if (data[0].toLowerCase().equals("bicycle")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
            System.out.println(data[3]);
            System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean(data[4]));
        }
        else if (data[0].toLowerCase().equals("auto")) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
            System.out.println(data[3]);
            System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean(data[4]));
        }
    }
}
```

and just like the setter functions, you can create getter functions and check if the values have been correctly stored.

Comment: I have updated the if condition. Could you please check on this.

Answer (score 0):

So, this line:

```
 String [] data = line.split("%");
```

...takes strings like this:

`"Bicycle%4%2%ABC40%false"` or `"Auto%22%7%ABC21%false"`

and turns them into arrays of strings like this:

```
data[0] : `Bicycle`  or  `Auto`
data[1] : `4`        or  `22`
data[2] : `2`        or  `7`
data[3] : `ABC40`    or  `ABC21`
data[4] : `false`    or  `false`
```

So now you just need to parse those strings into their `int` and `bool` equivalents:

```
speed        = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
passCap      = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
serialNumber = data[3]; // This is a string, right?
locked       = Boolean.parseBoolean(data[4]);
```

If serialNumber is a numeric, then you probably only want the numeric part at the end (e.g. `"21"` vs `"ABC21"`):

```
serialNumber = Integer.parseInt(data[3].Substring(3));
```

Comment: Yeah Scott The Serial Number is a String.  Can you see any reason why that my attributes wouldnt be pointing to the class?  Theyre all red saying "cannot find symbol"  I checked caps,spelling etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "attributes pointing to the class" - can you post the actual code that's showing up in red?

Comment: OK, there are additional issues in your code: **(1)** You've defined a `public static Object myBicycle`, but later you're creating a local variable `Bicycle myBicycle = ...`. That's not an error, but it's probably not doing what you wanted/expected. **(2)** Somewhere, you've defined classes for Vehicle, Auto and Bicycle. Do you have the necessary `using` statements at the top of your source file? If not, it could be that the compiler doesn't know what a 'Bicycle' type is. *P.S.: Don't forget to up-vote answers when people help you* ;-)